# Get links with 02x02 in url with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a little problem. I'm trying to learn regex, but I cant solve this problem.
I have a list of urls with this pattern:

```
http://domain.com/something/03x05/something/something.html
http://domain.com/something/something/something.html
http://domain.com/something/02x02/something/something.html
etc...
```

So I need to extract URL's with "03x05" or "02x02". I tried to use "/[0-9]x[0-9]/" but I don't get any url.

Can you help me?

Comment: `[0-9]x[0-9]` means "*a single digit between 0 and 9 followed by the letter "x" followed by a single digit between 0 and 9*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something quick, try the following regex:

```
.*?[0-9]x[0-9].*
```

**Explanation:**

```
.*?   # match any character except newline (lazily) 
[0-9] # character class matching any digit
x     # literal character 'x'
[0-9] # character class matching any digit
.*    # match any character except newline (greedily)
```

**Code:**

```
preg_match_all('/.*?[0-9]x[0-9].*/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://domain.com/something/03x05/something/something.html
    [1] => http://domain.com/something/02x02/something/something.html
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/138846)

Answer (score 2):

Use `/(03x05)|(02x02)/` should do the trick